# Only Debugging mode works in C# Visual Studio. Does not run in standard 'Run without Debugging'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Basically, I installed a project from my instructor that I *think* had inconsistent namespaces or something of the sort. I'm not 100% sure.

Now when I run that project (or ANY new project through File->New Project), I got an empty cmd window with a blinking cursor. There seems to be no response to keyboard input.

BUT, when I start with debugging, the program runs perfectly.

I have tested this with both VS 2012 Express and VS 2013 Pro which are both on my desktop, same results with any new projects as well as the one I downloaded from my instructor.

[image: With Normal Run]

[image: With Debugging]

I'm wondering if this may have nothing to do at all with the project given by my instructor, and may have to do with my cmd.exe settings or something. I did change the default size and maybe I did something incompatible with Visual Studio, I don't know.

Instructors file: http://faculty.cascadia.edu/mpanitz/Courses/BIT142/Lessons/Lesson_06/PCEs/PCE_06.zip

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I don't think I broke anything when I changed the size of the cmd window defaults. I just checked my laptop, and it has the same issue with VS 2012 Express, and it has also opened that project from my instructor before. So I'm not sure, but maybe that project actually breaks something? I don't know

Another thing I should have clarified is that I can successfully run any old project I open, even when I edit it..

Comment: We've been having questions like this all week.  Uninstall Avast.

Comment: Wow. Well that worked. Thanks so much, I tried disabling Avast to no avail. But I guess it was still blocking something, because the uninstall did the trick. I hope Avast fixes this because I want _good_ protection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling Avast! Free Antivirus worked. Even when disable didn't.

Posting here because I want to mark it as *Answered*

Thank you Hans Passant